# Editing an already accepted answer after 60 days earns Necromancer badge

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer

I edited https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69694 today. Even though it was submitted and accepted only 11 days after OP, I got the [necromancer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/necromancer) badge for  the edit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about badges and such belong on MSE.

Comment: @Adnan, <s>why should this question be closed after moving to meta?</s> Sorry, misunderstood the comment.

Answer (score 5):

[Necromancer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer) is awarded for

> Answer a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more

The question was asked January 8, **2015**, so that's a lot more than 60 days.

The reason the badge was awarded today is that you just got the fifth upvote. The edit itself is unrelated to the badge, although you probably got the upvote because the edit bumped the question to the front page.

Comment: D'oh!​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: It also hasn't been 60 days since January 8 or 19, 2016.

Comment: @MartinBüttner D'oh!​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @MartinBüttner, the question is asked in 2015, it was one year old at the moment of posting the answer.

Comment: @Qwertiy Yes, but NBZ's assumption was that he edited the answer 60 days after the challenge/answer was posted (see question title).